# Prove $5^n + 2 \cdot 3^n - 3$ is divisible by 8 $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ (using induction)

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

> Prove $5^n + 2  \cdot 3^n - 3$ is divisible by 8 $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Base case $n = 1\to 5 + 6 - 3 = 8 \to 8 \mid 8 $

Assume that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}\to 8 \mid 5^n + 2  \cdot 3^n - 3$

Showing $8 \mid 5^{n+1} + 2  \cdot 3^{n+1} - 3$

$$5^{n+1} + 2  \cdot 3^{n+1} - 3$$ $$5\cdot 5^n + 2\cdot 3\cdot 3^n - 3$$ $$ (5^n + 2\cdot 3^n - 3) + 4\cdot 5^n + 2\cdot 2\cdot3^n $$ $$ 5\cdot(5^n + 2\cdot 3^n - 3) + 4\cdot 5^n + 2\cdot 2\cdot3^n - 4\cdot(5^n + 2\cdot 3^n - 3)$$

$$ [5\cdot(5^n + 2\cdot 3^n - 3)]  - [4\cdot 3^n - 12]$$

The first term divides by 8 but I am not sure how to get the second term to divide by 8.

Comment: Apply induction again ?

Comment: On $4\cdot 3^n - 12$?

Comment: Exactly! I think that will work

Comment: You do not need a 2nd induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $4\cdot 3^n-12=4(3^n-3)$, since $3^n-3$ is even $2\mid 3^n-3$. Hence $8\mid 4\cdot 3^n-12$.

To make it clear: $3^n-3$ is even, since for $n\geq 1$ it is $3^n$ odd, and

"odd-odd=even" Since $(2k+1)-(2l+1)=2k-2l=2(k-l)$ which is even.

Answer (score 1):

As $3^n$ is an odd number, $4\cdot 3^n\equiv 4~(mod~8)$, also $12\equiv 4~(mod~8)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$4 \cdot 5^n+4 \cdot 3^n$$ is clearly divisible by 8 cause once you take the 4 out it is the sum of two odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(m)=5^m+2\cdot3^m-3,$

$$f(n+2)-f(n)=5^n(5^2-1)+2(3^2-1)3^n$$ which is clearly divisible by $8$

$\implies8|f(n+2)\iff8|f(n)$

Now establish the base cases $f(0),f(1)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try reducing your expression mod 8. For example, what is $5^n$ mod 8? Since $5 \equiv 5$ and $5^2 = 25 \equiv 1$,

$5^n \equiv \begin{cases} 5, n \text{ odd} \\ 1, n \text{ even} \end{cases}$.

Now do the same for $3^n$, and add.

(This solution doesn't use induction.)

Answer (score 0):

If $f(m)=5^m+2\cdot3^m-3,$

Let use eliminate either of $5^n$ or $3^n$

**Method**$\#1:$

$$f(n+1)-5f(n)=3^n(6-10)-(3-3\cdot5)=4(3-3^n)$$

Now as $3^n$ is odd, for integer $n\ge0,3-3^n$ is even

$\implies f(n+1)-5f(n)$ is divisible by $8$

$\implies8|f(n+1)\iff8|f(n)$ as $8\nmid5$

Now establish the base case $f(0)$

**Method**$\#2:$

$$f(n+1)-3f(n)=?$$