# Prove $\frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17} \in \mathbb{N}$ by induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction, alternative-proof

Here is my attempted proof:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $S_n$ be the statement: $\frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17} \in \mathbb{N}$

Base case: $S_1$: $\frac{2^{4(1)}-(-1)^1}{17} = \frac{16+1}{17} = 1 \in \mathbb{N}$

Inductive step: $\forall n \geq 1$, $S_n$ holds

$S_{n+1}$: $\frac{2^{4(n+1)}-(-1)^{n+1}}{17} = \frac{2^{4n} \cdot 2^4 +(-1)^{n}}{17} = \frac{2^{4n} \cdot (2^4+1) - 2^{4n} +(-1)^{n}}{17}$.

Now, we are left with $2^{4n} - \frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17}$.

We know $\frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17}$, $2^{4n} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $2^{4n} > \frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17} \implies 2^{4n} - \frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17} \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Is my proof correct? I also feel there is a more elegant/smoother proof (assuming mine is correct).

Comment: Yes there is a more direct proof.  Try to factor the numerator, $2^{4n} - (-1)^n$, as a difference of $n$th powers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554949/prove-5n-2-cdot-3n-3-is-divisible-by-8-forall-n-in-mathbbn-using/2555077#2555077

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine.

But note:

$(a - b)(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a^kb^{n-1 -k}) =$

$a(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a^kb^{n-1 -k}) - (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a^kb^{n-1 -k})=$

$(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{k+1}b^{n-1 - k}) -(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-k}) = $

$(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a^jb^{n-j})-(\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}a^jb^{n-j})=$

$([\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} a^jb^{n-j}]+a^nb^{n-n}) - (a^0b^{n-0}+[\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} a^jb^{n-j}]) = $

$a^n - b^n$.

So for all integers $a,b$ and  $n\ge 1$ we will always have $a-b$ divides $a^n - b^n$

So $2^4 -(-1) = 17$ will always divide $(2^4)^n - (-1)^n$.

Comment: fleablood.Very clear, very nice.

Comment: fleablood.I delete it.Thanks:)

Comment: **Simpler** $ $ let $\,x = a\!-\!b\,$ in $\,x\mid f(x)\!=\!(x\!+\!b)^n\!-b^n,\,$ by $\,f(0) = 0\ \ $  **QED**   $ $ Or, use congruencea, or the Binomial Theorem, etc. There are many *simple* ways to prove the **Factor Theorem**.

Comment: Hmmm.... fair enough.  But I think being direct is often best.  ANd this is direct..... Any way $(a-b)|(a^n - b^n)$ is a basic result and no matter how you prove it, this question is an immediate result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. *Conceptually* the induction follows very simply by *multiplying* the congruences below using  CPR = [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), $ $ i.e. raise $\ 16\equiv\, -1\ $ to the power $n$ by inductively multiplying

$$\begin{align}\bmod 17\!:\qquad \color{#c00}{16}\ &\equiv\ \color{#c00}{{-}1}\\
16^{\large n}&\equiv (-1)^{\large n}\qquad\quad\ P(n)\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \color{#c00}{16}\,16^{\large n}&\equiv (-1)^{\large n}(\color{#c00}{-1})\quad\ P(n\!+\!1)\end{align}\quad\ \ \ $$

i.e. the proof is a special case of the  (inductive) proof of the [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Thus the use of congruences has highlighted innate *arithmetical* structure allowing us to reduce the induction to an easy one $\,a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a^n\equiv b^n,\,$ with obvious inductive step: multiply by $\,a\equiv b\,$ via the product rule.

If you don't know congruences we can preserve this *arithmetical* essence by using an analogous *product rule* for *divisibility*, with  $\ m\mid n\ $ meaning $\,m\,$ divides $\,n,\,$ namely

$$\qquad\ \begin {align}
&17\mid\  \color{#c00}{16\,\ \ -\ \ B}\qquad\quad\ \  [B = -1\,\ {\rm in\  OP}]\\
&17\mid\ \ \  \ \ 16^{\large n} -\ B^{\large n}\qquad\ P(n)\\
\Rightarrow\ \ &17\mid\ \color{#c00}{16}16^{n}\! -\!\color{#c00}BB^{\large n}\qquad\ P(n\!+\!1)
\end{align} $$

$\begin{align}{\bf Divisibility\ Product\ Rule}\ \ \ \  
&m\mid\  a\ -\ b\qquad {\rm i.e.}\quad \   a\,\equiv\, b\\
&m\mid \ \ A\: -\: B\qquad\qquad \ A\,\equiv\, B\\
\Rightarrow\ \ &\color{}{m\mid aA - bB}\quad  \Rightarrow\quad aA\equiv bB\!\pmod{\!m}\\[.2em]
{\bf Proof}\,\ \  m\mid (\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})A + b(\color{#0a0}{A\!-\!B}) &\,=\, aA-bB\ \ \text{by $\,m\,$ divides $\rm\color{#0a0}{green}$ terms by hypothesis.}\end{align}$

You can find further discussion in [many prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20%22divisibility%20product%20rule%22)

Comment: Bill.Deleted it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, assuming $\frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17} \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\begin{align}\frac{2^{4(n+1)}-(-1)^{n+1}}{17} &= \frac{2^{4n} \cdot 2^4 +(-1)^{n}}{17} =\\
&=\frac{2^{4} \cdot (2^{4n}-(-1)^n) + 2^{4}(-1)^n +(-1)^{n}}{17}=\\
&=2^4\cdot \underbrace{\frac{2^{4n}-(-1)^n}{17}}_{\ge 1}+(-1)^{n}\in \mathbb N.
\end{align}$$