# $2^{2n+1} +1$ divisible by $3$

Tags: induction

$2^{2n+1} +1$ divisible by $3$

**Inducción over n**

Let $n=1$, then: $$2^{2(1)+1}+1=2^{3}+1=9$$ 
It works!

**Hip.** $$2^{2n+1} +1=3k$$

**Then we have to show:** $$2^{2n+3} +1=3k$$

Any guess?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea:

$$2^{2n+3}+1=4\cdot2^{2n+1}+1=\overbrace{2^{2n+1}+1}^{=3k,\,\text{by Ind Hyp.}}+\color{red}3\cdot2^{2n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$2^{2n+3} +1=2^2 \cdot 2^{2n+1} +1\stackrel{Hyp.}=2^2(3k-1)+1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$2^{2n+3}+1=(2^{2n+3}-2^{2n+1})+(2^{2n+1}+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

*Conceptually* the induction follows very simply by *multiplying* the congruences below using  CPR = [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $ $ as follows 
$$\begin{align}\bmod 3\!:\qquad \color{#c00}{2^{\large 2}}\ &\equiv\ \ \ \color{#c00}{1}\\
2^{\large 2n+1}&\equiv -1\qquad\ \ P(n)\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \color{#c00}{2^{\large 2}}\,2^{\large 2n+1}&\equiv -1\cdot \color{#c00}{1}\quad\ P(n\!+\!1)\end{align}\quad\ \ \ $$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2964810/242) for further discussion, including how to do the above without congruences.